# Do we need a [hardware] reset on this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, ambiguous-tags

The [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware) tag (here on MSE) is a bit of a mess. Here's the wiki:

> This tag is for questions about the hardware the Stack Exchange software uses to either build or run their software. Do not use this tag for questions about other hardware.

Unfortunately, that isn't how it's being used. I've seen

- Off-topic questions about hardware (that get closed and deleted) (one question - likely will be deleted soon)
- A proposal for a site about electrical engineering (one question)
- Site recommendations for questions relating to hardware (five questions)
- Questions pertaining to SE's process (or lack thereof) for hardware destruction (one questions)
- If a hardware question is on-topic on Stack Overflow (one questions)
- Inquiries regarding/pertaining to the hardware used by SE (four questions)

It seems only the last one is in line with the tag wiki. Unfortunately, that... is not how this tag is mostly being used. I don't know that this warrants a burnination, although it's somewhat of a mess.

What should be done with the [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware) tag on MSE? Some ideas include

- Burninate it
- Re-tag to follow the tag wiki
- Replace the tag wiki; then retag
- Split the tag into smaller tags, then burninate and retag

Comment: I think this tag is deeply problematic on every single site in the SE network. I just recently saw it on Electrical Engineering, bit of a WTF moment... is electronics _hardware_, really!?! On SO the tag is a veritable trash magnet, might as well have a tag named "off-topic" and it would serve the same purpose. And it makes even less sense on sites dealing exclusively with "hardware" (Hardware Recommendations, Home Improvement, Bicycles etc).

Comment: It has only eleven questions.

Comment: Well more precisely, looking at how the tags are used, they're mostly *about* SE's hardware - and part of how there was a lot of cross company involvement in meta. 

I feel like a more precise tag, clearly stating its *about* SE hardware and/or operations might be of value - if/when such posts are needed anew or updated, though that leads to a question of a generic subclass of such tags.

Answer (score 3):

The tag is ok. Just retag when needed, according to the tag excerpt.

P.S. I just retagged a few questions having [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware).

---

Remember that questions posted in Meta Stack Exchange should be about Stack Exchange and topics that are of interest or affect the whole network, or to several sites.

Some of the questions between 2008 and 2010 might be about a single site. Most of the tags that are specific to one site, like [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow), [serverfault](/questions/tagged/serverfault), among others, are a legacy from that time when there weren't per-child metas, sometimes referred to as Stack Exchange 1.0.

There might be a few tags that could be about features that are exclusive to one side, like [collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives).  If there are any tags about the scopes / topics belonging to specific sites, they might be part of the legacy tags, there might be a few needed to handle exceptional situations that require to be discussed here. In the case of [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware) it doesn't look like a legacy tag or a tag required to handle an exceptional situation. It's tag excerpt clearly states that it refers to hardware used by Stack Exchange / to run the software that powers the sites.